# Testing scenario to test remote API through Proxy server

Tags: api-testing, rest-api, proxy

I'm working on Remote API testing. Now we decided to pass every request through proxy server to fetch the endpoints. I just wanted to know is their any special scenario that I need to focus.

Thanks.

Comment: It is unlikely you will get an answer. Please read: [how to ask](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what not](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and do some research first.... This is too vague.